# Delete item from SQLite and listView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

i want to delete item from a listView and SQLite database with contextMenu and my code doesnt remove anything. Maybe someone can help me?

**DBAdapter.java**

```
public void delete(String name)throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        if (db == null) {
            return;
        }
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { name };
        db.delete("m_TB", "NAME"+ "=?", whereArgs);
        db.close();
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add("Delete");
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        String name = info.toString();
        if (item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
            db.delete(name);
            books.remove(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `long i= db.delete("m_TB", "NAME"+ "=?", whereArgs);` its give you your delete query run's or not.....................i value greater than 0 than query run else problem with query.

Comment: i thinck problem is from this part : if (item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) , your item dont match

Comment: This code didnt work..

Comment: i tested it with a Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); and it showed when held on item, and pressed delete